# Extended use of replace filter in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

i checked out the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) for the replace filter in twig. my problem is that, suppose i have a variable say `contvariable`, and the content passed through that variable from the controller is dynamic

```
 return $this->render('RodasysFormstudyBundle:Default:addclientname.html.twig', array('contvariable' =>$sometext));
```

this `$sometext` variable will contain texts like

```
$sometext='%Sun% rises in the East';
```

the text inside the `%%` should be displayed as an `input field` in the browser. I did not find any examples in the web like to replace the content inside the `%%` (what ever the content be whether its sun or the moon). Is this possible to do this using `replace` filter  or should i follow some other method such as to replace the content in controller before sending it to twig..

please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that (with the 'raw' filter) :

```
{{ "%foo% rises in the East"|replace({'%foo%': "<input type='text' name='"~foo~"' value='"~foo~"'/>"})|raw }}
```

**foo** is a variable sent by your controller, with the value of your choice.

Comment: you don't seem to get my question!.actually you don't know what the content comes in between the %% i hope i could get such that what ever the content in the %% not only foo. it should be a input field. is that possible.?

Comment: Actually it seems you can't use the replace filter with a dynamic name. You should write your own twig extension to do so, or pass 'contvariable' with keywords between %% AND the values to replace the keywords then. (Doing the replacement in the controller would be pretty ugly)

Comment: no as for my site its not possible to send the variable between %% alone the variable 'contvariable' contains both words which are not in %% and which are in.hope if anyone come up with a solution for this.

Comment: But how do you create 'contvariable' ? Where does the %% come from ? I think you will have to play with preg_replace or something like that.

Comment: preg_replace... thats with php. is there something like that in twig.??

Comment: Unfortunately, no regex in the Twig core (https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/546)